# Calendar class in Codeigniter not showing next/previous months

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to generate a calendar and almost have it, but when I click the next or previous links, the calendar is not displayed - otherwise it is correct. When I click the next url the address bar shows the correct url, but the next month is not shown.

Here is my code:

```
class Poll_controller1 extends skylark {

function poll_home()
{
    $this->add_to_center(POLL,"poll_view1");
    $this->load_lcr_template();
    $prefs = array (
           'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
           'next_prev_url'   => 'http://skylarkv2/index.php/poll_controller1/show'
         );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
}

function show()
{
    echo $this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
}
```

Am I making mistake or missing something?

Comment: I'm assuming the missing closing brace is a copy/paste mistake, and these are two separate functions in your controller...? I added one, please edit it back if this was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

try this from controller

```
 public function display($year = null, $month = null)
    {
            $config = array(
            'show_next_prev' => 'TRUE',
            'next_prev_url' => base_url().'calendarC/display'
            );
            $this->load->library('calendar', $config);
            $data['calendar'] = $this->calendar->generate($year, $month);
            $this->load->view('calendar', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you just need to initialize the [calendar class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/calendar.html) in the same scope that you generate it. The way you have it set up, `show()` has no knowledge of how the class was initialized in `poll_home()`. Try something like this:

```
function show()
{
    $prefs = array (
       'show_next_prev'  => TRUE,
       'next_prev_url'   => 'http://skylarkv2/index.php/poll_controller1/show'
     );

    $this->load->library('calendar', $prefs);
    echo $this->calendar->generate($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
}
```

There's also the chance that `$this->uri->segment(3)` and `$this->uri->segment(4)` are not what you think they are, double check that those values are correct. If you are have any routing going on, you may need to use `$this->uri->rsegment()` instead (note the **r**).